# Xcode 11: How do I get my content to display like this in landscape and portrait orientation?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, mobile

How would I go about doing something like this?

[portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttmAF.png)

[landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruvFZ.png)

I understand I need to use constraints, and I understand why, but I cannot wrap my head around actually applying the concept.

Comment: show what you have tried and what you got?

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if this will solve your problem, but can be done with very little code with SwiftUI:

```
'''
  VStack {
        HStack {
            Image("yourImageNameNoExtension")
            Image("yourImageNameNoExtension")
        }
        HStack {
            Button(action: {// Code you wish to run}) {
                Text("Button")
            }.padding()

            Button(action: {// Code you wish to run}) {
                Text("Button")
            }.padding()
        }
     }
'''
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since this isn't tagged as SwiftUI, why are you offering an answer? Additionally, the question implies **constraints**, which is **not** a part of SwiftUI.

Comment: why not offer an answer? Just trying to be helpful and this is a way of doing it - and without worrying about constraints ;)

Comment: This isn't really the intent of this site - which is simply Q&A. SwiftUI? It requires iOS 13, has many gaps in it's functionality, and... well, isn't UIKit. Your "answer" is analogous to me asking "Do you have anything to eat?" and your reply is "I'm too tired to tell you my age."